# Kotlin - Create new list with list(s) as argument using listOf()

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I want to create a List, Map or other collection from one or more Lists, Maps or other collection.

In dart you use the following syntax to produce a list of one or more lists:

```
List<int> l1 = [1, 2];
List<int> l2 = [3, 4, 5];
List<int> result = [...l1, ...l2];
//result == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In Kotlin I tried to do the same:

```
val l1 : List<Int> = listOf(1, 2)
val l2 : List<Int> = listOf(3, 4, 5)
val result: List<Int> = listOf(l1, l2);
//does not compile
```

Is the any way to unfold lists like the `...` syntax in dart?

Comment: `listOf(l1,l2).flatten()` or `l1 + l2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kotlin you can just use l1 + l2.

```
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val list2 = listOf(3, 4, 5)
val list3 = list1 + list2 #[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Also , [plus](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/plus.html) is another convient operation.

Comment: technically `plus` and `+` are exactly the same thing, as `plus` is defined as an `operator fun`. Things can get unclear if you're invoking `plus` explicitly. Example: try running `-1.plus(2)` and the result will surprise you :-) The actual correct form of that line would be `(-1).plus(2)` or `-1 + 2`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this! as previous answers suggested.
But the exact same behavior of `...` does not exists in Kotlin Lists.

But you can spread an Array using `*` (array spread operator).

For example if you have:

```
val array1 = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val array2 = arrayOf(4, 5, 6)
val array1AndArray2 = arrayOf(*array1, *array2)
```

The result of array1AndArray2 will be arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

But as far as I know, this behavior is not supported with Lists

For more information check: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
val result: List<Int> = l1.plus(l2)
```

Comment: There are a lot of things he can use but you have given no reason why he should use this.